# Logstash-OpenSearch: index is not created from provided template file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, opensearch

Due to AWS migration I have to migrate from `ElasticSearch` to `OpenSearch`. I am using `Logstash` to populate `index` with the DB data. In the existing Logstash's [elasticsearch output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-manage_template) configuration the `index` was created during the Logstash’s startup by setting `manage_template`, `template_name` and `template` properties. I want to keep the same behaviour for `OpenSearch` as well. I switched to [logstash output opensearch](https://github.com/opensearch-project/logstash-output-opensearch) plugin and have a following config:

```
output {
    opensearch {
      hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
      index => "ps_local_20220810083001"
      document_id => "%{id0}"
      template_name => "cas-template"
      template => "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/template/cas-template.json"
      manage_template => "true"
      template_overwrite => "true"
    }
}
```

The `Logstash` successfully starts,

```
[2022-08-18T12:09:02,990][INFO ][logstash.outputs.opensearch][programs] Using mapping template from {:path=>"/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/template/cas-template.json"}
[2022-08-18T12:09:02,993][INFO ][logstash.outputs.opensearch][programRules] Using mapping template from {:path=>"/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/template/cas-template.json"}
[2022-08-18T12:09:03,093][INFO ][logstash.outputs.opensearch][programRules] Installing OpenSearch template {:name=>"cas-template"}
[2022-08-18T12:09:03,094][INFO ][logstash.outputs.opensearch][programs] Installing OpenSearch template {:name=>"cas-template"}
```

but I don't see the index template has been created in OpenSearch. The following API's requests provide confusing results. As I understand, the template has not been created:
[image]
[image]

As a result the index documents created using auto-mapping do not correspond the required structure.
I tried to create a template manually before starting the Logstash. In that case documents looks good. But I do want the Logstash to create the template and index.

**Question:** Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

**UPDATED:**
As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73403235/5284890), I should be using the old API to check the specific template details `GET http://localhost:9200/_template/cas-template`. It shows that the template was created but the `mapping` section is empty:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first screenshot you get from `_cat/templates` shows that the template exists.

The template is still a legacy template stored [via the `_template` API](https://github.com/opensearch-project/logstash-output-opensearch/blob/main/lib/logstash/outputs/opensearch/http_client.rb#L391-L395) and not the new `_index_template` API.

So if you run the following, you should find your template:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_template/cas-template
```

Now as to why the index is created with a default automatic template and not the one that was just installed, it's because you're using the new composable template format with the old legacy template endpoint. Make sure that your `/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/template/cas-template.json` file contains the legacy format and not the composable one. The notable difference is that in the new format everything is wrapped in a section called `template: {}`

Comment: Thanks Val for pointing out these details. Let me check the the `template` itself, as I updated it to match the new  `_index_template API`. I will get back.

Comment: Also, I make `GET http://localhost:9200/_template/cas-template` call to check the template details. The mappings, settings, aliases sections are empty. I added the response sample to the question.

Comment: Composable templates (i.e. `_index_template`) take precedence over legacy templates (i.e. `_template`). If no composable template matches a given index, a legacy template may still match and be applied. So beware if you have the template defined twice, once as composable and once as legacy. The Logstash output only creates legacy templates

Comment: I know why the sections are empty: it's because you're using the new composable template format with the old legacy template endpoint. Make sure that your `/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/template/cas-template.json` file contains the legacy format and not the composable one. The notable difference is that in the new format everything is wrapped in a section called `template: {}`

Comment: Thanks, I am checking it now. Will run everything from scratch and let you know.

Comment: Everything started working. Thanks for your support and sharing all these details. It would be much easier if all that would be document somewhere.

Comment: Do you want to update you answer so I will mark it as an answer for my issue?

Comment: It's already updated ;-)

Comment: I was expecting to find it in OpenSearch documentation, under Logstash section. Thanks.

Comment: True that Opensearch is not really consistent since their documentation only handles the [new composable templates](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/index-templates/) even though the Logstash `opensearch` output leverages the legacy `_template` API. ‍♂️